# Magento 1.5.0.1 checkout issue on IE over ssl

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.5

Magento checkout is working fine, on all other browsers except IE, it gets stuck over billing section [STEP-2], and when I click continue it does not proceed further?

I tried with both account checkout / guest checkout, none of them works in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked many internet articles and found that people solved this kind of issue with introducing div col-right block, but in my case it was not helping out, I checked for ajax reload progress url and progress.phtml file too, but in Magento 1.5.0.1 this file does not exist. so none of the solution worked that I read about IE magento checkout issue.

The fix which saved me is this

Go to File :

```
/app/code/community/Jira/MageBridge/Model/Rewrite/Url.php
```

around line 89:

change the line below

```
protected function isSecurePage($routePath = null){
```

To

```
protected function isSecurePage($routePath = null)
{
  $routePath = preg_replace('/\*\//',
    Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestedRouteName().'/', $routePath);
  $routePath = preg_replace('/\/\*\//',
    Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestedControllerName().'/', $routePath);
```

This fixed actually https SSL issue. that was got blocked by IE. I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Javascript error reporting for Internet Explorer and/or install an Internet Explorer javascript debugger.  You're running into a Javascript error that breaks all the other javascript on the page, and prevents the checkout from proceeding.  There's myriad reasons this could be happening, and without seeing your error messages it's impossible to debug. Once you see your error messages, you'll be able to answer.